# Should I break into subnets

Tags: subnet

I am a working on designing a network for a new volunteer ambulance headquarters.  I am trying to decide if I should use Sub nets and how to group them. As of now the network load is going to be made up of, 36 IP based security cameras, around 20 ip phone extensions,  1 server that holds all the call report data, IP camera server, 7 work stations, 2 network printers, WIFI for 3 call  reporting devices to connect to the server, separate WIFI for public usage, access control doors and the HVAC system talks to all of the different parts over the network.

Comment: especially if you are going to have a public WiFi network, subnets and vlans, this is not an architecture support forum though.

Answer (score 1):

Probably no, except the public WiFi segment.

Comment: Agreed. Except for the public WiFi, I don't see much of a case for segmenting the network.